# redirect uri not working using Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I'm trying to get my login url to go thru my controller, so what I did was I added the redirect uri, but my redirect uri seems to be having problems because it says page not found.
(I'm using codeigniter)
URL Sample:

```
www.mywebsite.com/somewords/thisfile/function?code=somerandomcode
```

But when I check if I'm connecting to the correct controller function, it gets there.
URL Sample:

```
www.mywebsite.com/somewords/thisfile/function
```

I don't know which side is causing the problem,is it my configuration for facebook or my codeigniter settings or I just did something wrong.

Comment: To determine what is wrond `echo $fb->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=>'gohere'))`. Does printed string contains `"redirect_uri=gohere"`? If so, URL generation is not problem.

Comment: It actually goes there, so it's probably not the facebook configuration isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, as you say, not Facebook problem. Is this `somewords/thisfile/function` real part of URL you want to redirect? Since function cannot be named `function` it may be problem.

Comment: the url was just I sample, I had a different name for my function, so somewhat I am quite puzzled as to why it's not connecting, even though I could access the url if I remove the code.

Comment: Then it's some silly CodeIgniter routing issue. After some Google time I found you need to enable query strings in CI. Look for `enable_query_strings` in configs and set to true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable query strings for CI in configs

```
// application/config/config.php

$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: And I think I still had to change the uri_protocol to "REQUEST_URI"